# Give roles permission to interact with newly created channel Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using Node.JS to create a discord bot in which a new role and channel are created with the same command.  For the sake of simplicity, both the name of the role and the name of the channel are the first argument of the command:

```js
let chanName = args[0];
let roleName = args[0];
```

Following the name of the role/channel is a list of mentions - these are the users that receive the new role.  The role is created just fine, the channel is created just fine, and the members are added to the role just fine, but I'm having trouble setting up permissions where only users with the new role OR the 'administrator' role are able to see the channel.

The channel is created like so:

```js
message.guild.channels.create(chanName, {
    type: "text"
})
.then((channel) => {
    //Each new channel is created under the same category
    const categoryID = '18-digit-category-id';
    channel.setParent(categoryID);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

It appears as though the channel is not added to the guild cache

```js
let chan = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === chanName);
```

because this code returns 'undefined' to the console.

Is there any way I can allow the mentioned users to interact (view, send messages, add reactions...) with this new channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are very simple to set up upon creating a channel!
Thanks to the multiple options [GuildChannelManager#create()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) gives us, we're very simply able to add permission overwrites to our desired roles and members.
We could very simply take your code and add a `permissionOverwrites` section to set the channel's permissions, as follows:

```
message.guild.channels.create(chanName, {
        type: "text",
        permissionOverwrites: [ 
           // keep in mind permissionOverwrites work off id's!
            {
                id: role.id, // "role" obviously resembles the role object you've just created
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
            }, 
            {
                id: administratorRole.id, // "administratorRole" obviously resembles your Administrator Role object
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
            },
            {
                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
            }
        ]
    })
    .then((channel) => {
        //Each new channel is created under the same category
        const categoryID = '18-digit-category-id';
        channel.setParent(categoryID);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you once again for the response!  I do have a few questions:  I'm currently creating the channel and then the role - it would make sense to me that I should now swap them around?  And how do I get the ID of a role that I just created if it is not yet in the cache?

Comment: Yes! You would want to first create the role then use it for the permissions.

You can very simply define the role you've just created and then use it later while using `permissionOverwrites`!

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm quite new to this.  How do I 'define the new role'?  I tried `let newRole = message.guild.roles.create...` as well as `roleName.id` (as the name of the new role is defined as `roleName`), but I'm getting an error that says the argument passed is neither a role, nor a user.

Comment: You have actually gotten it right at first.
You have defined it just correctly, and will now simply have to use `newRole.id`!
Also, just a quick tip, I'd suggest working with `const` with cases where you don't need to change the variable later. It's sometimes a lot cleaner and easy to edit later on if you have any errors.

Comment: Okay, I changed it so `newRole` is now a constant, but I'm still getting the "TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role." error.

Comment: Could you please message me on discord (Bqre#0001) and show me your code?